# Implement pagination using Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, pagination

I'm trying to implement pagination using Spring MVC and Hibernate.

Here is my DAO layer:

```
private static final int LIMITITEMSPERPAGE = 6;

public List<Video> listVideosByKids(int page) {

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Video where type=1");
    query.setMaxResults(LIMITITEMSPERPAGE);
    query.setFirstResult(page * LIMITITEMSPERPAGE);

    return (List<Video>) query.list();

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listKids(@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("listVideos", videoService.listVideosByKids(page));
        return "/kids/list";
    }
```

When i go to URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/kids/list/?page=0
```

I get first 6 items from database and everything works fine.
But i would like to get first 6 items without get param **page** in URL, just:

```
http://localhost:8080/kids/list/
```

But if i'll open url:

```
http://localhost:8080/kids/list/?page=1
```

then i get second 6 items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit `http://localhost:8080/kids/list/` request param **page** is missing. You can add default value to it with required to false.

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listKids(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue="0", required=false) int page, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("listVideos", videoService.listVideosByKids(page));
        return "/kids/list";
    }
```